# Number of ways of arranging people into parties.

Tags: combinatorics

A person wishes to form as many parties of $10$ as he can out of $20$ people. The number of ways he can do this if the same man is to be included in all the parties is ?

The answer to this question is $\binom {19}{9} $ . Is it because , out of the twenty people that the man wishes to arrange , a particular person is to be found in all the possible number of parties that can be formed. Hence he (that person) does not need to be included in the number of possible ways that the parties can be formed. Therefore we now only have $19$ people to arrange , and considering that a particular person is to be found in all the parties , the remaining nine places can be filled by the $19$ people in $\binom {19}{9} $ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly the answer is yes.
Imagine the following steps:

1. The "same man" is pulled out of the 20 people.
2. Parties of 9 are formed from the 19 people left.
3. The "same man" is put into each of the parties formed in step 2 making them parties of 10.

I may have just repeated what you said.

Comment: Thank you for the verification!